# Tempo de execução função recursiva

Tags: java, recursão

Como eu calculo o tempo de execução de uma função recursiva?

```
 public void ordenar(int vetor[],int i,int f){
    boolean aux2=true;
    int inicio=i,fim=f;
    while(i<f){
        if(vetor[i]>vetor[f]){
            int aux=vetor[i];
            vetor[i]=vetor[f];
            vetor[f]=aux;
            aux2=!aux2;
        }
        if(aux2)
            f--;
        else
            i++;
    }
     for(int x=0;x<vetor.length;x++){
        System.out.print(vetor[x]+" ");
    }
    if(i>inicio)
        ordenar(vetor,inicio,i-1);
    if(i<fim)
        ordenar(vetor,i+1,fim);
}
```

Comment: Só pra constar, usar `System.currentTimeMillis` não é a melhor maneira de medir o tempo de execução/desempenho de algo (leia [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103) para entender melhor). Prefira usar ferramentas especializadas - eu costumo usar o [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh), mas no link já indicado tem outras opções

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso seria mais interessante você fazer as medições de início e fim antes e depois da chamada do método recursivo. Crie um método para realizar essa medição.

Ex:

```
public void Exemplo(){
   Exemplo();
}

public long calculaTempo(){
    long comeco=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Exemplo();
    long fim=System.currentTimeMillis();

    return fim - comeco;
}
```

OBS> Considere o método **Exemplo** como um método recursivo